# Is there any way to make cordova (alone) to serve files by http://localhost:port instead of file://?

Tags: cordova, angular

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I am not talking about the cordova serve command. I am talking about the app running in the device/emulator.

I know that it is possible to install some plugin to enable a local web server, but cordova itself still serves files as file://.

I know too that there are lots of hybrid apps frameworks and i even tried one of them (meteor js). It was a HUGE PAIN, because you can't just put you angular 2 web app within meteor... you have to make an infinite number of adaptations, lots of bizarre errors... horribly non-productive (not to mention the slowness... jesus). Just for a comparison, my angular 2 app compiled and optimized with AoT runs like a rocket with cordova...

Although, running an app with file:// may not be an immediate problem, but it will be when you start to face CORS issues and related. Running from an "http://" would really make life easier.

I appreciate any thoughts and ideas, Thanks.

Comment: Hey, I need the same thing actually, have you found any solution?